# SQL group-by statement with having-clause in Matlab

Tags: matlab, merge, group-by, having

I have two tables in `Matlab` that I would like to merge, ´Returns´ and ´Yearly´, according to the following `SQL` statement. How do I merge them in `Matlab`? (I have to use Matlab)

```
select a.*, b.Equity, b.Date as Yearly_date from Returns a, Yearly b where a.Id = b.Id and a.Date >= b.Date group by a.Id, a.Date having max(b.Date) = b.Date
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Returns = table([repmat(1,5,1);repmat(2,6,1)],[(datetime(2013,10,31):calmonths(1):datetime(2014,2,28)).';(datetime(2013,10,31):calmonths(1):datetime(2014,3,31)).'],randn(11,1),'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Return'})

Returns = 

    Id       Date         Return 
    __    ___________    ________

    1     31-Oct-2013     -0.8095
    1     30-Nov-2013     -2.9443
    1     31-Dec-2013      1.4384
    1     31-Jan-2014     0.32519
    1     28-Feb-2014    -0.75493
    2     31-Oct-2013      1.3703
    2     30-Nov-2013     -1.7115
    2     31-Dec-2013    -0.10224
    2     31-Jan-2014    -0.24145
    2     28-Feb-2014     0.31921
    2     31-Mar-2014     0.31286

Yearly = table([repmat(1,3,1);repmat(2,2,1)],[(datetime(2011,12,31):calyears(1):datetime(2013,12,31)).';(datetime(2012,12,31):calyears(1):datetime(2013,12,31)).'],[8;10;11;30;28],'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Equity'})

Yearly = 

    Id       Date        Equity
    __    ___________    ______

    1     31-Dec-2011     8    
    1     31-Dec-2012    10    
    1     31-Dec-2013    11    
    2     31-Dec-2012    30    
    2     31-Dec-2013    28
```

I would like the following output:

```
 ans = 

    Id       Date          Return      Equity    Yearly_date
    __    ___________    __________    ______    ___________

    1     31-Oct-2013      -0.86488    10        31-Dec-2012
    1     30-Nov-2013     -0.030051    10        31-Dec-2012
    1     31-Dec-2013      -0.16488    11        31-Dec-2013
    1     31-Jan-2014       0.62771    11        31-Dec-2013
    1     28-Feb-2014        1.0933    11        31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Oct-2013        1.1093    30        31-Dec-2012
    2     30-Nov-2013      -0.86365    30        31-Dec-2012
    2     31-Dec-2013      0.077359    28        31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Jan-2014       -1.2141    28        31-Dec-2013
    2     28-Feb-2014       -1.1135    28        31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Mar-2014    -0.0068493    28        31-Dec-2013
```

Comment: Could you write down the expected output?

Comment: argh... I will try... :)

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: Sorry, still not clear to me as probably that SQL didn't look that "readable" to me. So, if I could bother you again, do you mind explaining the expected output for the `Id = 1`

Comment: Sure, for each row in table Returns, I want to merge it with the row from the other table, Yearly, that has the same id, and where the Yearly.Date is the newest date that is *still* less than or equal to Returns.Date. So for Id = 1 and Date = '31-Oct-2013' in Returns, I want to merge it with row 2 in Yearly, since the Ids are the same, and '31-Dec-2012' is the newest Date still less than or equal to '31-Oct-2013'.

Comment: Does it make more sense?

Comment: And the `Return` column (col-3) in the output seem to have different values than `Return` column in Returns table?

Comment: That is just a mistake - i put in random values. They should be exact same as in Returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes another **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based solution, abusing its *masking capability* -

```
%// Inputs
Returns = table([repmat(1,5,1);repmat(2,6,1)],[(datetime(2013,10,31):...
    calmonths(1):datetime(2014,2,28)).';(datetime(2013,10,31):calmonths(1):...
    datetime(2014,3,31)).'],randn(11,1),'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Return'})
Yearly = table([repmat(1,3,1);repmat(2,2,1)],[(datetime(2011,12,31):...
    calyears(1):datetime(2013,12,31)).';(datetime(2012,12,31):calyears(1):...
    datetime(2013,12,31)).'],[8;10;11;30;28],'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Equity'})

%// Get mask of matches for each ID in Returns against each ID in Yearly
matches = bsxfun(@ge,datenum(Returns.Date),datenum(Yearly.Date)'); %//'

%// Keep the matches within the respective Ids only
matches(~bsxfun(@ge,Returns.Id,Yearly.Id'))=0; %//'# Or matches(bsxfun(@lt,..)

%// Get the ID (column -ID) of the last match for each Id in Returns
[~,flipped_col_ID] = max(matches(:,end:-1:1),[],2);
col_ID = size(matches,2) - flipped_col_ID + 1;

%// Select the rows from Yearly based on col IDs and create the output table
out = [Returns table(Yearly.Equity(col_ID), Yearly.Date(col_ID))]
```

Code run -

```
Returns = 
    Id       Date         Return 
    __    ___________    ________
    1     31-Oct-2013    0.045158
    1     30-Nov-2013    0.071319
    1     31-Dec-2013     0.52357
    1     31-Jan-2014    -0.65424
    1     28-Feb-2014      1.8452
    2     31-Oct-2013    0.037262
    2     30-Nov-2013     0.38369
    2     31-Dec-2013      1.1972
    2     31-Jan-2014    -0.54708
    2     28-Feb-2014    -0.15706
    2     31-Mar-2014     0.11882
Yearly = 
    Id       Date        Equity
    __    ___________    ______
    1     31-Dec-2011     8    
    1     31-Dec-2012    10    
    1     31-Dec-2013    11    
    2     31-Dec-2012    30    
    2     31-Dec-2013    28    
out = 
    Id       Date         Return     Var1       Var2    
    __    ___________    ________    ____    ___________
    1     31-Oct-2013    0.045158    10      31-Dec-2012
    1     30-Nov-2013    0.071319    10      31-Dec-2012
    1     31-Dec-2013     0.52357    11      31-Dec-2013
    1     31-Jan-2014    -0.65424    11      31-Dec-2013
    1     28-Feb-2014      1.8452    11      31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Oct-2013    0.037262    30      31-Dec-2012
    2     30-Nov-2013     0.38369    30      31-Dec-2012
    2     31-Dec-2013      1.1972    28      31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Jan-2014    -0.54708    28      31-Dec-2013
    2     28-Feb-2014    -0.15706    28      31-Dec-2013
    2     31-Mar-2014     0.11882    28      31-Dec-2013
```

---

### Generic case solution

For cases, when the `Ids` could be non-numeric and the `dates` aren't sorted already, you may try out the following code -

```
%// Inputs
Returns = table([repmat('Id1',5,1);repmat('Id2',6,1)],[(datetime(2013,10,31):...
    calmonths(1):datetime(2014,2,28)).';(datetime(2013,10,31):calmonths(1):...
    datetime(2014,3,31)).'],randn(11,1),'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Return'})
Yearly = table([repmat('Id1',3,1);repmat('Id2',2,1)],[(datetime(2011,12,31):...
    calyears(1):datetime(2013,12,31)).';(datetime(2012,12,31):calyears(1):...
    datetime(2013,12,31)).'],[8;10;11;30;28],'VariableNames',{'Id','Date','Equity'})

%// -- Convert strings based Ids into numeric ones
alltypes = cellstr([Returns.Id ; Yearly.Id]);
[~,~,IDs] = unique(alltypes,'stable');
lbls_len = size(Returns.Id,1);
Returns_Id = IDs(1:lbls_len);
Yearly_Id = IDs(lbls_len+1:end);

%// Get Returns and Yearly Dates
Returns_Date = datenum(Returns.Date);
Yearly_Date = datenum(Yearly.Date);

%// Sort the dates if not already sorted
y1 = arrayfun(@(n) sort(Returns_Date(Returns_Id==n)),1:max(Returns_Id),'Uni',0);
Returns_Date = vertcat(y1{:});
y2 = arrayfun(@(n) sort(Yearly_Date(Yearly_Id==n)),1:max(Yearly_Id),'Uni',0);
Yearly_Date = vertcat(y2{:});

%// Counts of Ids to be used as boundaries when saving output at each
%// iteration correspondin to each ID
Yearly_Id_counts = [0 ; histc(Yearly_Id,1:max(Yearly_Id))];
Returns_Id_counts = histc(Returns_Id,1:max(Returns_Id));

%// Initializations
stop = 0;
col_ID = zeros(size(Returns_Date,1),1);

for iter = 1:max(Returns_Id)

    %// Get mask of matches for each ID in Returns against each ID in Yearly
    matches = bsxfun(@ge,Returns_Date(Returns_Id==iter),...
        Yearly_Date(Yearly_Id==iter)'); %//'

    %// Get the ID (column -ID) of the last match for each Id in Returns
    [~,flipped_col_ID] = max(matches(:,end:-1:1),[],2);

    %// Get start and stop for indexing into output column IDs array
    start = stop + 1;
    stop = start + Returns_Id_counts(iter) - 1;

    %// Get the columns IDs to be used for indexing into Yearly data for
    %// getting the final output
    col_ID(start:stop) = Yearly_Id_counts(iter) + ...
        Yearly_Id_counts(iter + 1) - flipped_col_ID + 1;

end

%// Select the rows from Yearly based on col IDs and create the output table
out = [Returns table(Yearly.Equity(col_ID), Yearly.Date(col_ID))]
```

Code run -

```
Returns = 
    Id        Date         Return 
    ___    ___________    ________
    Id1    31-Oct-2013     0.53767
    Id1    30-Nov-2013      1.8339
    Id1    31-Dec-2013     -2.2588
    Id1    31-Jan-2014     0.86217
    Id1    28-Feb-2014     0.31877
    Id2    31-Oct-2013     -1.3077
    Id2    30-Nov-2013    -0.43359
    Id2    31-Dec-2013     0.34262
    Id2    31-Jan-2014      3.5784
    Id2    28-Feb-2014      2.7694
    Id2    31-Mar-2014     -1.3499
Yearly = 
    Id        Date        Equity
    ___    ___________    ______
    Id1    31-Dec-2011     8    
    Id1    31-Dec-2012    10    
    Id1    31-Dec-2013    11    
    Id2    31-Dec-2012    30    
    Id2    31-Dec-2013    28    
out = 
    Id        Date         Return     Var1       Var2    
    ___    ___________    ________    ____    ___________
    Id1    31-Oct-2013     0.53767    10      31-Dec-2012
    Id1    30-Nov-2013      1.8339    10      31-Dec-2012
    Id1    31-Dec-2013     -2.2588    11      31-Dec-2013
    Id1    31-Jan-2014     0.86217    11      31-Dec-2013
    Id1    28-Feb-2014     0.31877    11      31-Dec-2013
    Id2    31-Oct-2013     -1.3077    30      31-Dec-2012
    Id2    30-Nov-2013    -0.43359    30      31-Dec-2012
    Id2    31-Dec-2013     0.34262    28      31-Dec-2013
    Id2    31-Jan-2014      3.5784    28      31-Dec-2013
    Id2    28-Feb-2014      2.7694    28      31-Dec-2013
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! If some of the Id's are non-numeric, how can I find the matches within the respective Ids only? For this to work the data needs to be row sorted by Id and then by dates, right?

Comment: @Mace Yes, it assumes sorted Ids only, dates could be anything. So, if the Ids are not already sorted, one can easily use `sort` as pre-processing. And by non-numeric, do you mean something like strings maybe?

Comment: Yes, strings. How to incorporate this?

Comment: @Mace Check out the **Edit** section?

Comment: I have tried flipping the order of Yearly.Date, and the output is now wrong, so I think that the order of the dates matter too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! Would prefer not having to change the Id's. Is it not possible to change the line comparing Id's?

Comment: @Mace Well you don't have to change the `Ids`, I have put in there to sort of make it plug-n-play. So, instead you can edit the original solution code - `matches(~bsxfun(@ge,IDs(1:lbls_len),IDs(lbls_len+1:end)'))=0`, keeping rest of the code as it was.

Comment: I just tried using your solution on my real tables, and I got an out-of-memory error in the first line using bsxfun. The real tables are 2090808x7 and 164909x6. Any idea for a solution that would work with this big tables?

Comment: Looks good - thanks a lot! I have tried it on my real data set, but I have some Id's in Returns that are not in Yearly. It results in errors. Any idea how to handle this and add NaN in these cases?

Comment: @Mace So, does the latest question you have asked [Unique doesn't remove all table-row duplicates in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28279311/3293881) solves the `NaN` issue with this problem?

Comment: I have actually given up on solving this in Matlab. I have now loaded the data into an sql server database, and done it there. It became too complicated for such a small select.