# Unique doesn't work with Table having NaN entries - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a `table` with duplicate rows that I try to remove with `unique` in `Matlab`. However, I doesnt work for all of them. This toy example illustrates my point. Any ideas of how, I remove them?

```
AAA = table(repmat('0122',2,1),repmat('011',2,1),repmat(NaN,2,1))

ans = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____

    0122    011     NaN 
    0122    011     NaN 

unique(AAA)

ans = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____

    0122    011     NaN 
    0122    011     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introductory Discussion

Mathworks documentation on **[`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)** states the following -

> `C = unique(A)` returns the same data as in A, but with no
>   repetitions.
>
> If `A` is a table, then `unique` returns the unique rows in `A`. The
>   rows of table `C` are in sorted order.

So, for the case of `table` as input to `unique`, it suggests that it's basically like `unique(....'rows')`, if only you can ID each entry of that table. The trick we use here is to convert all those entries into cells of a cell array and then ID each cell and then use those numeric IDs with `unique(...'rows')`.

### Function Code

The code listed next does just that -

```
function Tout = unique_table(T)

%// Convert input table into a cell array
Tcell = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),table2cell(T),'Uni',0);

%// ID all cells of the cell array
[~,~,id_cells] = unique(Tcell);

%// Use the cell IDs to find the unique row IDs
[~,unq_rowid] = unique(reshape(id_cells,size(Tcell)),'rows');

%// Use the row IDs to get the expected table with unique rows
Tout = T(unq_rowid,:);

return;
```

### Test runs

**Case #1: Original case**

```
T = 
    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____
    0122    011     NaN 
    0122    011     NaN 
Tout = 
    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____
    0122    011     NaN
```

**Case #2: Modified case**

```
T = 
    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____
    0122    011      56 
    0122    011     NaN 
Tout = 
    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____
    0122    011      56 
    0122    011     NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have run into a problem because of the `NaN` values.

Hidden in the documentation, it is mentioned that:

> unique treats NaN values as distinct.

I suppose you could work around this by substituting nan values with a dummy value before using unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Inf` instead of `NaN`:

```
>> AAA = table(repmat('0122',2,1),repmat('011',2,1),repmat(inf,2,1))

AAA = 

Var1    Var2    Var3
____    ____    ____

0122    011     Inf 
0122    011     Inf 

>> unique(AAA)

ans = 

Var1    Var2    Var3
____    ____    ____

0122    011     Inf
```

Comment: What if the first entry of `Var3` is `NaN` and second entry is `Inf`? With this substitution based solution, both the entries would become `Inf` and thus would be considered as duplicates and that isn't expected.

Comment: i usually use NaN or Inf to initialize variables which i would give them values later. And with NaN, from Matlab's website: `Because two NaNs are not equal to each other, logical operations involving NaN always return false, except for a test for inequality, (NaN ~= NaN)`, it is not recommended if you intend to use such logical functions (comparision) like `unique`